# Calcular letra DNI Java e imprimirla

Tags: java

El ejercicio.

```
/*
      Crea una clase persona cuyos datos tenga: 
      1. El nombre, la edad, y el DNI.
      2. Crea sus métodos set y get.
      3. La variables son privadas.
      4. Calcula la letra del DNI.
      5. Imprime.
*/
```

El problema está en que no se como calcular la letra del DNI, es lo único que me falta.

```
package boletin;

public class Personas {

    public String nombre;
    public int edad;
    public int dni;

    public Personas(String nombre, int edad, int dni) {
        this.nombre = nombre;
        this.edad = edad;
        this.dni = dni;
    }

    public int getEdad() {
        return this.edad;
    }

    public String getNombre() {
        return this.nombre;
    }

    public int getDni() {
        return this.dni;
    }

    public void setEdad(int edad) {
        this.edad = edad;
    }

    public void setNombre(String nombre) {
        this.nombre = nombre;
    }

    public void setDni(int dni) {
        this.dni = dni;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Personas[] personas = new Personas[5];
        Personas[] person = new Personas[5];
        personas[0] = new Personas("Juan  ", 53, 12345678);
        personas[1] = new Personas("Gema  ", 42, 23456789);
        personas[2] = new Personas("Javier", 20, 34567891);
        personas[3] = new Personas("Marina", 17, 45678912);
        personas[4] = new Personas("Danko ", 10, 56789123);

        for (Personas persona : personas) {
            System.out.println("El dni es " + persona.dni + " su nombre es " + persona.nombre + " y su edad es de " + persona.edad);
        }
    }
}
```

Eso es lo único que me falta y no encuentro nada con lo cual solucionarlo. Y muchas gracias por adelantado.

Crea una clase persona cuyos datos tenga:
1. El nombre, la edad, y el DNI.
2. Crea sus metodos set y get.
3. La variables son privadas.
4. Calcula la letra del DNI.
5. Imprime.

Comment: Vea: [Cálculo del dígito de control del NIF/NIE](http://www.interior.gob.es/web/servicios-al-ciudadano/dni/calculo-del-digito-de-control-del-nif-nie).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Para calcular la letra de un DNI tan solo hay que dividir la parte numérica del DNI entre el numero de diferentes letras que puede tener un DNI. Te pongo un ejemplo con java:

```
int dni = 12345678;
//El string de letras es fijo y deberían de ir en este orden
String letras = "TRWAGMYFPDXBNJZSQVHLCKE";
//La letra correspondiente será el resto de la división del número del DNI entre las 23 posibilidades que hay
char letra = letras.charAt(dni % letras.length());
String dniEntero = "" + dni + letra;
System.out.println(dniEntero);
```

Eso imprimirá `12345678Z`

Comment: lo voy a mirrar muchas gracias

Comment: Si te ayuda recuerda marcarlo como respuesta :)

Comment: si que me ayudo muchas gracias

Answer (score 0):

La solución la tengo gracias a benito-b muchas gracias de verdad. Hizo un codigo facil y sencillo lo he modificado un poco y me ha quedado asi.

```
package boletin;

public class Personas {

    public String nombre;
    public int edad;
    public int dni;

    public Personas(String nombre, int edad, int dni) {
        this.nombre = nombre;
        this.edad = edad;
        this.dni = dni;
    }

    public int getEdad() {
        return this.edad;
    }

    public String getNombre() {
        return this.nombre;
    }

    public int getDni() {
        return this.dni;
    }

    public void setEdad(int edad) {
        this.edad = edad;
    }

    public void setNombre(String nombre) {
        this.nombre = nombre;
    }

    public void setDni(int dni) {
        this.dni = dni;
    }

    public String calcularLetra() {
        String letras = "TRWAGMYFPDXBNJZSQVHLCKE";
        //La letra correspondiente será el resto de la división del número del DNI entre las 23 posibilidades que hay
        char letra = letras.charAt(dni % letras.length());
        String dniEntero = "" + letra;
        return dniEntero;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Personas[] personas = new Personas[5];
        Personas[] person = new Personas[5];
        personas[0] = new Personas("Juan  ", 53, 12345678);
        personas[1] = new Personas("Gema  ", 42, 23456789);
        personas[2] = new Personas("Javier", 20, 34567891);
        personas[3] = new Personas("Marina", 17, 45678912);
        personas[4] = new Personas("Danko ", 10, 56789123);
        for (Personas persona : personas) {
            System.out.println("El dni es " + persona.dni + "" + persona.calcularLetra() + " su nombre es " + persona.nombre + " y su edad es de " + persona.edad);
        }
    }
}
```